# First time deploy a sharepoint 2010 project

Tags: 2010, deployment

I'm learning sharepoint 2010 developing. After some theoretical pages in "Inside Microsoft Sharepoint 2011" I'm finally ready to start creating sollutions myself.

I've installed everything local. (Sharepoint, SQL-server-2008 express, visual studio 2010, Sharepoint tools for vs 2010) And i have i sharepoint site running on my local pc as well on an external server. I can browse both sharepoint website in my browser.

Local website: https://my-pc:81

When i try to deploy my sharepoint project in visual studio 2010 it fails because of the error shown below:

> "Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Cannot connect
>   to the SharePoint 
>   site: http://my-pc:81/. Make sure that this is a valid URL and
>    the
>   SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this
>   project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has
>   changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property
>    of the project."

And Also the following warning message:

> "Unhandled exception occurred while calling method 'ProjectService_ProjectPropertiesRequested' of type 'CodeCounsel.SharePoint.DevTools.ProjectExtensions.ProjectExtension, CodeCounsel.SharePoint.DevTools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f275076a3ecf8ed7'. Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Utilities, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Can someone guide me through the first steps to successfuly deploy (and debug) a sharepoint sollution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I forgot to specify port 81 to my Alternate Access Mappings

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you mention the Site URL property in Visual Studio project?. You can check the project Properties and make sure Site URL is the Web application where you want solution to be deployed

Comment: Yes, i did changed to propertie of my project. You can see the value of that property in my error message. When i browse to the value of this property, i can see my sharepoint site.

Comment: Go to Central admin -> Application Management -> Manage Web applications and check the URL of Web application where you're deploying your solutions. I'm just making sure that your solutions are deployed to correct Web application, not the Central Admin URL.

Comment: Double checked. Central administration is running on port 6578. Do i have to provide credentials somewhere before deploying?

Comment: But in Application Management i see my site is running on port 80. The website was not found after installing sharepoint when using that port. Therefore i added a binding to port 81. Then i could see my sharepoint page by browsing to http://my-pc:81/  I guess this is the source of my problem?

Comment: I've found the answer. You brought me in the good direction :)

Comment: Ok good to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you: [http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2010/2/28/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-'recycle-iis-application-pool'.aspx](http://www.dev4side.com/community/blog/2010/2/28/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-%27recycle-iis-application-pool%27.aspx)

Comment: This is what i already did, i filled in the correct url in the property field. I also have another warning message when trying to deploy. I'll edit my question.